# Values of variables don't change when creating new processes in C

Tags: c, process, execve

I am coding an assignment for school in c and we are using processes for this. My goal is to assign some random values to a structure, and when I try to assign some random number to one specific process through an execve, every other process keeps the same value when it should change it.

So this is the code I have written to create the processes and run an execve on them

```
    for (int i = 0; i < init_people; ++i) {
    switch (pids[i] = fork()) {

        case -1:
            fprintf(stderr,"Error #%03d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
            break;

        case 0:
            switch (i % 2) {
                case 0:
                    execve("./A",args,NULL);
                    break;                      
                case 1:
                    execve("./B",args,NULL);
                    break;                     
                default:
                    break;
            }
            exit(0);
            break;               
        default:
            waitpid(pids[i], &returnStatus, 0);
            break;
  } }
```

And the execve of A.c and B.c is just as simple as this

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

```
int r;
srand(time(NULL));
r = rand() & 11;
printf("%d\n", r); 

return 0;
```

}

For every time I run this code it always gives me one random value that keeps being the same for all the execution while it should change every time I run the execve file for every process. How can I fix this? I am forced to using execve and can't change that.

Comment: remember, every new process gets a COPY of the data, so changing the value in one process has no effect on the data  in any other process

Comment: when calling any of the `exec...()` functions, always follow the call with `perror( "exec..() failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: the posted code, in  the `default` case following the call to `fork()`  will result in the main process starting a child process, then waiting for that child to complete before starting another process.   Suggest moving that call to `waitpid()` to inside a new loop, after  the end of the `for()` code block

Comment: this statement: `fprintf(stderr,"Error #%03d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));` fails to tell the user that it was a call to `fork()` that failed.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  3) treat the closing brace '}' as a separate statement.

Comment: regarding: `execve("./A",args,NULL);`  `args[0]` should point to the same file name (not the path) as the first first parameter to `execve()`

Comment: when using the `execve()` function, the new process `main()` function should have three parameters.  I.E. `int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time()` returns whole seconds. It's highly likely that all the `fork+execve` combos will complete under a second, which means the value of `time(NULL)` will be the same in each executed child process. If you want the pseudo-random  generators of the child processes to be initialized differently, you could use `getpid()` instead of `time(NULL)`.